# cDataTable (Core UI React) is not showing data properly

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I am new to React and Core UI and would be really great if someone could assist me on this.

I am fetching users to my cDataTable from an API. Currently I have 12 users in the database.
As shown below my current page is 1 and records per page is 10. This works fine

[image]

But when i navigate to page 2 cDataTable shows no results. But according to the React developer tools I can see that I have 2 users fetched from the API.

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this??

p.s: I have tried fetching users on page 1 after records per page changed to 25 and it gets me back my 12 users from the API

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the coreui team below solved the issue.

in CDataTable - remove pagination props- pagination, activePage, itemsPerPage

Below CDataTable create separate CPagination component, which will contain currently requested page